# Twilio how do I configure libcurl

Tags: php, curl, twilio, libcurl

I am using Twilio,after I setup in my localhost i run the simple script and I get this error message.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_TinyHttpException' with message 'SSL certificate problem
```

I see some answers here suggesting to download the latest libcurl see https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/docs/faq.rst#ssl-validation-exceptions

I immediately download this file `curl-7.42.1` see http://curl.haxx.se/download.html then when download is done I extract the folder.Now I am stuck I don't know what to do to configure in twilio.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [downloading curl-7.42.1 and installing in windows machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498926/downloading-curl-7-42-1-and-installing-in-windows-machine)

Comment: try to set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false and remove any other SSL options